# Multipart ImageUpload with Param data in IOS

Tags: ios, multipart

I am trying to upload image with some text data. But When i try it for image upload only. it works! But for param, I am getting **result=null**. so data is sending null. here is my code.

```
-(void)uploadImage : (UIImage *)image : (NSString *)url : (NSString *)param
{
NSLog(@"URL : %@", url);
NSLog(@"param : %@", param);
NSData *myData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSMutableURLRequest *request;
NSString *urlString = url;
NSString *filename = @"image";
request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSDictionary *temp = @{@"result"     : @"rob"
                        };
//opening boundary
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@.png\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:myData]];
//params
[postbody appendData:[ [temp description] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//closing boundary
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:postbody];

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
//  conn.delegate = self;
[conn start];

}
```

may any expert help me what i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a library like AFNetworking for all your requests. It's very easy and makes your code more readable. Here is a way to create a multipart file upload with parameters (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#creating-an-upload-task-for-a-multi-part-request-with-progress)

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
    @"result" : @"rob"
}

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://example.com/upload" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.jpg"] name:@"file" fileName:@"filename.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" error:nil];
    } error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSProgress *progress = nil;

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
    }
}];

[uploadTask resume];
```

Comment: may you fix it without library help?